# Transaction message

Tags: sql-server-2005

In activity monitor the process details shown as ]
`"SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;BEGIN TRANSACTION".`what does it means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this link of msdn : [SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259216(SQL.80).aspx)

**READ COMMITTED**

Specifies that shared locks are held while the data is being read to avoid dirty reads, but the data can be changed before the end of the transaction, resulting in nonrepeatable readsor phantom data. This option is the SQL Server default.